# Перебор сочетаний из n по k

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика, c

Помогите с алгоритмом поиска все сочетаний из n по k без повторений.

Например сочетания из 4 по 3:

1. 0 1 2
2. 0 1 3
3. 0 2 3
4. 1 2 3

Нашел алг на Delphi, но не могу переделать под Си.

```
var
    i,p,k,n,m: integer;
    A: array [1..100] of integer;
begin
    readln(k,n);
    {генерация первого подмножества}
    for i := 1 to k do
        A[i]:=i;

    p:=k;
    while p>=1 do
    begin
        {вывод подмножества на экран}
        for m := 1 to k do
            write(A[m],' ');
            writeln;

        if A[k]=n then
            p:=p-1
        else
            p:=k;

        if p>=1 then
            for i := k downto p do
                A[i]:=A[p]+i-p+1;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: что именно не получилось сделать в Си?
нельзя по правилам писать за Вас код

Comment: дело в том что в делфи массивы начинаются с 1, но алгоритм мне не очень понятен, поэтому переделать не могу.
То что у меня получилось:

void gen_comb(int *arr, int n, int k)
{
    int i=0, j=0;

    arr = (int*)malloc(k*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < k; ++i) arr[i]=i;

    p=k;
    while(p>=1) {
        if(arr[k] == n) p-=1;
        else p=k;

        if (p>=1)
            for (i = k; i > p; --i)
            {
                arr[k] = arr[p]+i-p+1;
            }
    }
}

Comment: Может так:

arr = (int*)malloc(k*sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < k; ++i) arr[i]=i;

p=k-1;
while(p>=0) {
    if(arr[k-1] == n) p-=1;
    else p=k-1;

    if (p>=0)
        for (i = k-1; i > p; --i)
        {
            arr[k-1] = arr[p]+i-p+1;
        }
}
}

Answer (score 2):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C

Answer (score 1):

Нашел http://www.aconnect.de/friends/editions/computer/combinatoricode_e.html