# Генератор словаря из заданного диапазона чисел

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать генератор словаря на C# из заданного диапазона чисел.
К примеру дано число 20(назовём его словом) и количество слов в последовательности 5. Нули и повторения слов в последовательности не допускаются
Нужно сгенерировать двухмерный массив такой что:

```
1;2;3;4;5
1;2;3;4;6
1;2;3;4;7
1;2;3;4;8
1;2;3;4;9
1;2;3;4;10
.........
1;2;3;4;20
1;2;3;5;4
1;2;3;5;6
1;2;3;5;7
.....
1;2;3;5;20
.....
16;17;18;19;20

  int max = 20;

        int n = 2; // num of column


        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            if (b > max)
            {
                b = 1;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(j);

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    mas[i, j] = b;

                }
                if (a > max)
                {
                    a = 1;
                }
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    mas[i, j] = a;
                    a++;
                }

            }

            if (a > max)
            {
                b++;
            }

        }
```

В этом коде генерация последовательная, но есть повторения. 
По сути в задаче аналогия прорисовывается с числовой лотереей.
генерировать все возможные комбинации 5 из 20 и добавить их в двухмерный массив `[m,n]`, где `m = (20*19*18*17*16)/!5 = 15504 - количество строк; n = 5` количество слов в последовательности.

Comment: Число размещений без повторений из n по m (n различных элементов) вычисляется по формуле: `n! / (n - m)!` = `20! / (20 - 5)!` = `1860480`, долго будет считаться

Comment: Тут не совсем так вычисляется. Для любых n и k число сочетаний можно рассчитать по формуле: С(n, k) = n! / (k!·(n-k)!). количество вариантов будет на 2 порядка меньше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перебор сочетаний из n по k](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317017/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-n-%d0%bf%d0%be-k)

Answer (score 1):

Взято [здесь](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.23):

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int m, int n)
{
        int[] result = new int[m];
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(0);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
       {
            int index = stack.Count - 1;
            int value = stack.Pop();

            while (value < n) 
           {
                result[index++] = ++value;
                stack.Push(value);

                if (index == m) 
                {
                    yield return result;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}

static void Main()
{
    foreach (int[] c in Combinations(3, 5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", c));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я посмотрел вашу программу. Она генерит повторяющиеся последовательности. я попробовал это исправить, но пока не получилось. 1 2 3 4 5 
                     1 2 3 5 4 
                     1 2 4 3 5 
                     1 2 4 5 3 
                     1 2 5 3 4 
1 2 5 4 3 
1 3 2 4 5 
1 3 2 5 4 
1 3 4 2 5 
1 3 4 5 2 
1 3 5 2 4 
1 3 5 4 2 
1 4 2 3 5 
1 4 2 5 3 
1 4 3 2 5 
1 4 3 5 2 
1 4 5 2 3 
1 4 5 3 2 
1 5 2 3 4 
1 5 2 4 3 
1 5 3 2 4 
1 5 3 4 2

Comment: да нет, повторов я не нашел, возможно просто не так понял условие

Comment: понял что не так делал. добавил правильный код.